# Exporting QGIS layer as shape through REST API

Tags: export, qgis-server, rest, getfeature

I would like to export a layer described in QGIS Server project file as Shape through REST API. For example GeoServer's [GetFeature](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#wfs-getfeature) accepts `outputFormat` parameter value `shape-zip` which in turn returns Shape zip archive for the desired GeoServer layer.

Is there a way to accomplish the same with QGIS Server? [GetCapabilities](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#web-feature-service-wfs) on my QGIS instance declared that [GetFeature](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#id6) has following output formats:

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
    <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
    <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
    <ows:Value>application/vnd.geo+json</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
```

So I was wondering maybe I have missed something and maybe there is a way export layer data in same manner as with GeoServer (not looking for a plugin)?

Comment: You'll have to investigate how to add the shapefile zip as an output format for Qgis,perhaps by adding a GDAL driver like you can in mapserver. Otherwise Qgis WFS will not be able to give you that format directly as a result of a request response. You might also consider using a WPS to do the transformation